# Accessing controls within ControlTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, controltemplate

I have a `ControlTemplate` defined in a resource-dictionary file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ctlTemplate">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <StackPanel x:Key="sp" x:Name="sp">
                <TextBlock Name="tplTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <DataGrid  Name="tableBlock" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
            </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
 </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have a class that is derived from `Thumb` and i am trying to set its `Template` property to the above `ControlTemplate`:

```
Dim ct As ControlTemplate = CType(Application.Current.Resources("ctlTemplate"), ControlTemplate)
Dim tb As MovableTableBlock = New MovableTableBlock 'Derives from Thumb
tb.Template = ct
tb.UpdateLayout()
```

Problem is that the `Thumb` isn't rendered at all. However, if i remove the `ControlTemplate.Resources` tag and as a result also remove the `x:Key` property of the `StackPanel`, `Thumb` is rendered. The reason i am setting the `x:Key` property of the `StackPanel` is because i want to access the `TextBlock` and `DataGrid` children to set the text and data-binding respectively. Basically i just want to access the `StackPanel`'s children. How can i access them?

EDIT:
I have changed my `ControlTemplate` to this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VQ.Custom">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MovableTableBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MovableTableBlock}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="sp">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tplTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <DataGrid  x:Name="tableBlock" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So now, i do not have to set the template like this:

```
tb.Template = ct
```

Now the `Thumb` is rendered but i still cant access the inner controls as suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586.aspx). For some reason, `tb.Template` is `Nothing` when i do this:

```
Dim txtBlock As TextBlock = CType(tb.Template.FindName("tplTextBlock", tb), TextBlock)
```

Comment: The reason Thumb isn't rendered with this template is that your `ControlTemplate` has no visual implementation.  The resources do not make up the visual tree of the template.  I would recommend reading up on control templates.  [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jitghosh/archive/2007/12/27/wpf-control-templates-an-overview.aspx) is one place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an implicit style to set the template:

```
    <Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary2;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary2"
                 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
        <Application.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="local:MovableTableBlock">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MovableTableBlock">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="sp">
                                <TextBlock Name="tplTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <DataGrid  Name="tableBlock" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>

    // No need to set Template or Style on MovableTableBlock, as it's done implicitly
    MovableTableBlock mtb = new MovableTableBlock();
    mtb.UpdateLayout(); // pointless to do...as not in visual tree yet

    .....your mtb needs to be added to the visual tree e.g. add as child of
    Grid or other element, so the style and template can be applied....your
    OnApplyTemplate won't be called till then.

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        TextBlock tb = Template.FindName("tplTextBlock", this) as TextBlock;
    }
```

I've tried the above code, and it is able to get to the TextBlock in your template using the above method.

The way you are trying to change the Template is a bit unconventional...there are some suggestions below on how to organize a custom control.

---

When you are writing a custom control where you "expect" certain named elements to be present in the template, then it is a convention to name them as "parts" and to use the [TemplatePart] attribute on the custom control class. This is so that people that re-template the control, know which parts are crucial to be inside a redesigned template.

Also you mention that you are getting access to the TextBlock and DataGrid, so that you can set the text, and the DataBinding.

Instead of doing this, consider exposing some properties on your custom control...which your template then binds to using "`{TemplateBinding ...}`" or "`{Binding ...RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent} ...}`".

Also the way you are setting the template into your custom control by looking up the template from Resources and setting it in  code behind is unconventional....you should let that be picked up by a default style.

Here are some links that should help to explain:

- http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html
- http://xamlcoder.com/cs/blogs/joe/archive/2007/12/13/building-custom-template-able-wpf-controls.aspx

Comment: Your suggestion to add `x:Key` to `StackPanel` is not working. I get compile time error.

Comment: You don't need the x:Key....that's only need if it's in a ControlTemplate.Resources element....forgot to remove....have updated example.

Comment: Followed your `OnApplyTemplate`, but `FindName` returns `Nothing`

Comment: Is `GetTemplateChild` deprecated? VS tells me not to use it and use `FindName` instead.